# Calculating time taken for projectile to reach height (y) and position (xz) at that time in 3D space

Tags: unity, projectile-physics

I am trying to calculate, given a `Rigidbody` and a `float` height, at what time will the `Rigidbody` reach that height. Given my maths career was given up around 20 years ago, I am trying to convert some equations I found to accommodate this. Namely,

$$t=\frac{V_y+\sqrt{V^2_y+2\cdot g \cdot h}}{g}$$

I have the following function:

```
private void CalculateTimeToHeightAndPosition(Rigidbody rb, float targetHeight, ref float timeToHeight, ref Vector3 positionAtHeight)
{
    float ySpeed = rb.velocity.y;

    timeToHeight  = (ySpeed + Mathf.Sqrt((ySpeed * ySpeed) + (2 * -Physics.gravity.y * rb.transform.position.y)) / -Physics.gravity.y);

    if (!float.IsNaN(timeToHeight))
    {
        Vector3 v = rb.position + (rb.velocity * timeToHeight);

        positionAtHeight = new Vector3(v.x, targetHeight, v.z);
    }
    else
    {
        timeToHeight = 0f;
        positionAtHeight = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is this is not taking into account the `targetHeight`, and therefore calculates the time to ground, but I don't know how it fits into this equation. Anyone able to help in how to amend the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-factored the function to (mainly to keep track of the `a,b,c` variables) and it seems to have done the job. Simply taking the target position away from initial position seems to have been the answer. Rubber ducking at its finest.

```
private void CalculateTimeToHeightAndPosition(Rigidbody rb, float targetHeight, ref float timeToHeight, ref Vector3 positionAtHeight)
{
    float yTargetPos = targetHeight;
    float ySpeed = rb.velocity.y;
    float a = -Physics.gravity.y;
    float b = ySpeed;
    float c = rb.position.y - yTargetPos;

    timeToHeight = (b + Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(b, 2) + (2 * a * c))) / (2 * a);

    if (!float.IsNaN(timeToHeight))
    {
        Vector3 v = rb.position + (rb.velocity * timeToHeight);

        positionAtHeight = new Vector3(v.x, catchTargetHeight, v.z);
    }
    else
    {
        timeToHeight = 0f;
        positionAtHeight = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept your own answer, it might help people facing the same problem in the future!